# Where am I going wrong using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var s = "07:05:45PM";
var meridian = s.match("/[AM PM]/i"); //matches AM or PM in s

console.log(meridian); 
// Expecting output as [PM] but actual output is null
```

Trying to get whether it is AM or PM. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: You're passing a string to `s.match()` and not a regular expression. Because of that, the `/` characters are interpreted as being actually part of what you're trying to match.

Comment: also, read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to understand what `[AM PM]` actually means (match A or M or space or P or M)

Comment: Some languages (such as PHP) do indeed expect a regex to be specified in a string, but it's worth understanding which languages do not do this.

Comment: Pro-tip: I have edited some of your questions to remove please-help-me material. Consider that a title of `Could anyone help me where I am going wrong using regex` can be shortened to `Where I am going wrong using regex`, and thus much of it is redundant. Note that adding lots of "please help me" waffle is generally interpreted as begging, rather than as a politeness. This may be where your downvotes have come from (I have not voted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is really made up of two problems: your regular expression syntax and the value you're passing to `match`.

Placing text inside of square brackets in a regular expression (e.g. `[AM PM]`) means "match any one character that is declared in here." So doing `[AM PM]` translates to "Match an A, a P, an M, or a space." You would usually see such an expression written as `[AMP ]` (or any order of those characters). To match what you're looking for, try something like this:

```
[AP]M
```

which means "match either an A or a P followed by an M".

Then there's the problem of what you're passing to `match`. `match` should take a regular expression literal, not a string. Basically, remove the quotation marks.

Your final code could look like this:

```
var s = "07:05:45PM";
var meridian = s.match(/[AP]M/i); //matches AM or PM in s

console.log(meridian);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these

`/[AP]M/i` or `/(AM|PM)/i`

Your current regex is matching anything with only one the letters `[AMP ]`.

Also, don't wrap your regex in quotes, you want it to be a regex not a string.

Comment: perhaps note that it shouldn't be a string too :p

Answer (score 1):

You need a regular expression, not a string.

```js
var s = "07:05:45PM";
var meridian = s.match(/[AP]M/i); //matches AM or PM in s

console.log(meridian);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using groups not character sets.

`[AM PM]` matches a single character in that set (`A` or `M` or `P` or ).

`(AM|PM)` matches the entire string where `|` is an or. In the example, it will match `AM` *or* `PM`.

Second, the input to `match` should be a regular expression not a string (remove the double quotes).